# How to set values as optional for QueryParam for rest api call in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, query-string

Would like to know how to set queryParam values as @Optional for @QueryParam.

Tried the following

```
@QueryParam("x") int x
```

I want to set a defaultvalue for **x** and make it as optional.

I tried the following ways

```
@QueryParam("x") @DefaultValue("1") int x
```

But when I pass empty in

```
http://localhost:8100/sort/values?x=
```

My expectation is to get the value of x as **1** because as I am setting the **@DefaultValue("1")**

But I am getting the below error

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Because the **@DefaultValue** only accepts **String** and I am expecting a **int** datatype

Is there a way I can set a **defaultValue** and make it as **optional** for **@QueryParam** I can do this for **RequestHeader** but facing issues when I want the same kind of implementation for **QueryParam**

Please let me know if I am missing anything or any different kind of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`@DefaultValue` will kick in when the query parameter is missing in the URL, like below.

```
http://localhost:8100/sort/values
```

Since the request parameter 'x' is present without any value, the handler method received the value as empty string ("") for x and tried to convert it integer (as x is int) which eventually failed with that exception message.

If you want to handle empty values, then it can be done programmatically. We can use apache commons StringUtils library and convert the empty string to 1.

```
StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(x, "1")
```

Comment: 1. Without having **x** passed in the url it is failing with the below error
```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'x' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.handleNullValue(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:245)
```

2. And yes I wanted to convert using StringUtils but it is failing at the **rest layer** itself. any thoughts?

Comment: Use wrapper type Integer instead of primitve type (int)

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring as the tag suggest, you can try:

```
@RequestParam(required = false) String myParam
```

Comment: I have to use QueryParam, not RequestParam.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. So, `@DefaultValue` didn't work? I believe it must be before `@QueryParam` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RequestParam instead of @QueryParam
It has a required attribute that you can set to false

Example:

public String get(@RequestParam(required = false) int x) {}

Or default :

public String get(@RequestParam(defaultValue = 1) int x) {}